# What are the dangers of calling c from a go or java program?

Tags: java, go, java-native-interface

This can be done via standard mechanisms (e.g. JNI for java).  What happens if something goes wrong in the c lib? Say a segmentation fault. Will that crash the containing process?

By contrast, calling a go lib from a go program seems much safer (or java lib from a java program). The lib can throw an exception, but the container can move on. Of course, things like OutOfMemory can throw off the whole process, but at least it's clear what happened.

Answer (score 2):

> Say a segmentation fault. Will that crash the containing process?

There's not much difference in that respect between C called from C, and C called from Java.   A SIGSEGV will crash the process if unhandled; otherwise it will do whatever the handler does.  But in general, it's not wise to recover from random program behavior by ignoring critical failures; your address space is likely in some strange state you didn't write code to deal with.

The real issue with calling C through JNI is that C can corrupt Java structures (say, the JVM heap) in ways that by design are not possible in Java.  And the corruption doesn't show up until some time later, leading to frustration in debugging.

Comment: I assume the same is true when go calls c. You thought is that A java lib or go lib would be easier to debug. The options are X calls Y.   Where X can be {java,go} and Y is {X or c}.   X -> c seems less stable and harder to debug (not to mention implement and deploy).